# How to create a dataframe with aggregated categories?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (**df**) with the following fields:

| id | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Eddie | magician |
| 01 | Eddie | plumber |
| 02 | Martha | actress |
| 03 | Jeremy | dancer |
| 03 | Jeremy | actor |

I want to create a dataframe (**df2**) like the following:

| id | name | categories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Eddie | magician, plumber |
| 02 | Martha | actress |
| 03 | Jeremy | dancer, actor |

So, first of all, i create df2 and add an additional column by the following commands:

```
df2 = df.groupby("id", as_index= False).count()
df2["categories"] = str()
```

(this also counts the occurrences of various categories, which is something useful for what I intend to do)

Then, I use this loop:

```
for i in df2.itertuples():
   for entries in df.itertuples():
      if i.id == entries.id:
         df2["categories"].iloc[i.Index] += entries.category
      else:
         pass
```

Using this code, I get the dataframe that I wanted. However, this implementation has several problems:

1. Doesn't look optimal.
2. If there are repeated entries (such as another column with "Eddie" and "magician"), the entry for Eddie in df2 would have "magician, plumber, magician" in categories.

Therefore I would like to ask the community: is there a better way to do this?

Also keep in mind that this is my first question on this website!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby your `id` and `name` columns and apply a function to the `category` one like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  'id': ['01', '01', '02', '03', '03'],
  'name': ['Eddie', 'Eddie', 'Martha', 'Jeremy', 'Jeremy'],
  'category': ['magician', 'plumber', 'actress', 'dancer', 'actor']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = df.groupby(['id', 'name'])['category'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x)).reset_index()
df2
```

Output:

```
   id    name          category
0  01   Eddie  magician, plumber
1  02  Martha           actress
2  03  Jeremy      dancer, actor
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, works much faster than the loops that I was using previously!

Comment: Or... `df.groupby(['id', 'name'], as_index=False)['category'].agg(', '.join)`

Comment: Thank you @JonClements, this method works aswell.